# How speed up pytorch model loading time

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, aws, aws-lambda

I have deployed the background removal model( Pytorch- pre-trained u2net) in aws using lambda and EFS file system and APIgetway.
I have stored my model in efs and loading to the lambda. the model is around 170MB.
The API getaway response time is around 32 seconds. is it any way to speed up the response time?